# CFBundleVersion Mismatch - The CFBundleVersion value does not match the CFBundleVersion value of its containing iOS application

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I'm new to the whole app world, and this is my first time using X-code (my apps I have built in the past, use *Phonegap Build*)

Anyway - I managed to create a stick page (eventually!). Now I've made some changes to it, but I can't for the life of me work out how to upload it! I get this error when pushing it:

> CFBundleVersion Mismatch - The CFBundleVersion value '1' of extension
>   'Steampunk Junkies™ Sticker
>   Pack.app/PlugIns/StickerPackExtension.appex' does not match the
>   CFBundleVersion value '1.0.5.1' of its containing iOS application
>   'Steampunk Junkies™ Sticker Pack.app'.
>
> CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch - The CFBundleShortVersionString
>   value '1.0' of extension 'Steampunk Junkies™ Sticker
>   Pack.app/PlugIns/StickerPackExtension.appex' does not match the
>   CFBundleShortVersionString value '1.0.5' of its containing iOS
>   application 'Steampunk Junkies™ Sticker Pack.app'.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

My configs look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've never had to manage the version numbers in X-Code before - so its entirly possible I've missed an important step when changing the version number.

Could someone please help me out? It's driving me up the wall!

**NB:** I'm using *X-Code 8.2 beta* (the version they offer you to download from the developer area)

**UPDATE:** Thank you so much to shallowThought helping me on this! While my setup didn't quite look like he posted, it made me look around to find the place he was talking about. In the end, I found it with the "down arrow", as circled below:

[image]

Once I clicked that, it let me view the information of the other section of the package. Man, I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I consider it an App Store bug, caused by `StickerPackExtension` targets version and build version differs from the `Steampunk Junkies™ Sticker Pack` application targets version:

[image]

[image]

To fix the error simply copy the version to make sure they are the same for both targets.

If you can not see your targets, click this symbol: [image]

---

Update for newer Xcode versions:

When uploading to App Store, Xcode's Organiser now has a "Manage Version and Build Number" option which takes care of this issue by default, default is ticked:

[image]

Comment: Ah man, that was it! (slightly different, but it got me on the right track - I'll post an update above). Thank you for saving the remaining part of my hair! ;)

Comment: no problem - was just updating my OP the include the solution that worked :)

Comment: Actually you can have the error with the same version on both target

Comment: @thibautnoah you have to be more detailed to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you so much
I got the same problem 
its solved by changing the Build number

Comment: Can any one let me know if build number is different in target and extension still if we distribute it on AppStore is it any harm. Or any disadvantage. Please clear my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: @shashiGupta I am wondering same thing, it uploaded fine, and I have it ready to submit to App Store, I just hope they don't reject it because of this after waiting for review

Comment: @MadeByDouglas I have submitted the build for review and Apple submitted it successfully.

Comment: @shashiGupta ok thanks good to know, we ended up pushing another build with different fixes anyway

Comment: I could not find any specific Apple guideline, sometimes their warnings are warnings, sometimes, they are hints that the issue will block approval... I just released an app with *no* extension  that had mismatched version numbers in the project. (Also, I was able to distribute it in TestFlight as well).

Answer (score 7):

Look under the Info tab to see if you have updated it there also.

You can change the build number and keep the same version number in order to archive it and submit to the app store.

Answer (score 1):

- Just go to **Build Settings** of your target which is the cause of version mismatch warning.
- Search for **MARKETING_VERSION**

It is there. You'll most probably see that the version number of that target is different than the app, edit it. Voila!