# CFBundleVersion Mismatch -The CFBundleVersion of extension 'app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationExtension.appex' does not match the CFBundleVersion value

Tags: bitrise

I'm facing a similar error to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872389/cfbundleversion-mismatch-the-cfbundleversion-value-does-not-match-the-cfbundle) except I'm using Bitrise for iOS deployments:

We are receiving emails from Apple on each deployment of our app:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App" 7.0.0 (6723). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

> ITMS-90473: CFBundleVersion Mismatch - The CFBundleVersion value '896' of extension 'app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationExtension.appex' does not match the CFBundleVersion value '6723' of its containing iOS application 'app'.

> ITMS-90473: CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch - The CFBundleShortVersionString value '6.6.0' of extension 'app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationExtension.appex' does not match the CFBundleShortVersionString value '7.0.0' of its containing iOS application 'app'."

The problem appears to lie with the OneSignal extension we are using in the app however I am not aware how to solve this problem in Bitrise as there isn't a built in step to handle this. Our deployments are successful however these emails are an annoyance that are sent to the whole team on each release. Grateful for any answers that may help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this  ? I am also facing this issue with OneSignalExtension after the upgrade to use Xcode 15 and IOS 17.

Comment: @Erick Yes, please see the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to use "Xcode Project Info" step to generate a `$XPI_Version` output variable then to add the latest version of `Set Xcode Project Build Number` step for each app target you have. Add the `$XPI_Version` to this step's version number field.